# Customizing date format using POI's HSSFDataFormat

Tags: java, scala, apache-poi

I have to populate a xsl using POI library. I have custom format to use(dd.MM.yyyy hh:mm). POI has class BuiltinFormats wherein some formats are already defined.

how can we provide custom format? I see class HSSFDataFormat having method getFormat for this purpose. But constructor for this class is not public and hence I can't instantiate in in my code.

Is there a way out of it?

Comment: [Busy Developers' Guide to HSSF and XSSF Features](https://poi.apache.org/components/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html) -> [Data Formats](https://poi.apache.org/components/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#DataFormats)

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
workbook.getCreationHelper.createDataFormat.getFormat("dd.mm.yyyy h:mm")
```

Comment: I tried with this as: 
val format = workbook.getCreationHelper.createDataFormat.getFormat("dd.MM.yyyy hh:mm")
and I see format with some valid integer value. But when I do:
val formatAvailable = HSSFDataFormat.getBuiltinFormat("dd.MM.yyyy hh:mm),
I get formatAvailable -1, meaning the format is not available even though I have set it earlier.